# Merge every array of an sub-object

Tags: arrays, json, merge, jq

I have the two following json files.

file1.json

```
{"field1":{"item1":0,"array1":[0,0,0],"array2":[0,0],"array3":[0]},"field2":{"dummy":0}}
```

file2.json

```
{"field1":{"item1":1,"array1":[1,1,1],"array2":[1,1],"array3":[1]},"field2":{"dummy":0}}
```

I want to obtain this :

```
{"field1":{"item1":0,"array1":[0,0,0,1,1,1],"array2":[0,0,1,1],"array3":[0,1]},"field2":{"dummy":0}}
```

I am able to do it manually array by array but I would prefer a method to do it automatically for each array of field1. Does someone have a tip for me ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that file1.json and file2.json contain valid JSON. You can convert the quasi-JSON to JSON using jq by running: `jq -n -f fileN.json`

```
def extend_arrays(o):
  reduce keys[] as $k 
    (.; if (.[$k]|type) == "array" and (o[$k]|type == "array")
        then .[$k] += o[$k] else . end);

.field1 |= extend_arrays($second|.field1)
```

With these lines in the file program.jq, the invocation:

```
jq -c --argfile second file2.json -f program.jq file1.json
```

produces the required output:

```
{"field1":{"item1":0,"array1":[0,0,0,1,1,1],"array2":[0,0,1,1],"array3":[0,1]},"field2":{"dummy":0}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. However, for the future reader, program.jq must be on a single line. So, each newline of program.jq must be removed.

Comment: That is not the case.  Normally, you would put the program into a file named program.jq, which can contain new lines.

Comment: I saw in the forum that other people have an isssue with multiline program as me. Maybe it comes from the version I use (jq 1.4). In every case, it works for me by just removing new lines, so thanks again !

Comment: There has never been an issue with multiline programs in a file.